# How to Automatically Center Ellipses in Justified Text

Tags: pdftex, formatting, text, ellipsis

Consider the following excerpt from Plato's *Republic*:

[image]

See how nicely centered the elipsis is on the second to last line.

However (and frequently encounter this), when I try to produce such a paragraph in Latex (using Pdflatex):

\documentclass{article}

```
\begin{document}
\large

In \emph{Laws} 731 {\small{\scshape{B-C}}} Plato tells us again that the soul cannot combat injustice without the capacity for righteous indignation. The Stoics affected to deprecate anger always, and the difference remained a theme of controversy between them and the Platonists. \textit{Cf.} Schmidt, \textit{Ethik der Griechen}, ii. pp. 321 ff., Seneca, \textit{De ira}, i. 9, and \textit{passim.} Moralists are still divided on the point. \textit{Cf.} Bagehot, \textit{Lord Brougham :} ``Another faculty of Brougham \ldots is the faculty of easy anger. 398
\end{document}
```

I get this:

[image]

Notice how far to the right of center the ellipsis is.

QUESTION: Is there a way to correct this using Pdflatex so that the ellipses always appear "centered" in justified text?

Thank you.

Comment: You're missing a space: `\ldots\ `

Comment: I don't see where the problem is. The text you provided has not the same `linewidth` so the ellipsis doesn't fall at the same point. If you managed to fix your line width, it should be better. But anyway, why would anyone want the ellipsis to be centred like this? I don't even think that it was a will from the original typographer, appart from manually making the space between the dots bigger to fit it on an entire line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `ellipsis` package if you want even spacing around the ellipsis:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ellipsis}

\begin{document}
 
``Another faculty of Brougham \ldots\ is the faculty 

``Another faculty of Brougham \ldots{} is the faculty 

``Another faculty of Brougham \textellipsis\ is the faculty 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, ldots\ and \textellipsis\ both seem to work best.

Comment: Wow, LaTeX has a package for everything.